# Prevent submission of form until specified button clicked (thickbox dialog)

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, preventdefault, confirmation

I would like to make a modal confirmation window using jQuery & thickbox  on every form with 'confirm' class.

**Here's the HTML markup:**

```
<!-- The form below -->
<form id="myform" class="confirm" name="actionform" action="target.php">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="id" name="id" id="id"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="title" name="title" id="title"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Form elküldése"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<!-- The modal box and it's content below, called with tb_show() function -->
<div id="myModalConfirm" style="display:none">
    <div>
        <p>Are you sure?</p>
        <button id="yes">Yes, I'm sure</button><button id="cancel">No, cancel it</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So the problem:**

The modal dialog show up and works fine and the cancel button works but clicking on button#yes won't submit the form and I think it's because of the preventDefault() function.

**Here's the jQuery (I'm working from jquery.1.8.3 lib, so please care about the compatibility )**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.confirm').submit(function(e){
        var form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        tb_show("Megerősítés","#TB_inline?height=100&amp;width=200&amp;inlineId=myModalConfirm&amp;modal=true",null);
        $('button#yes').click(function(){
            $(form).submit;


            });
        $('button#cancel').click(function(){
            tb_remove();
            return false;
            });
    })

});
```

**======| The solution |==============================================================**
*It's for me but checkout the other goods below in comments :)*

```
$('form.confirm').submit(function(e, submit){
        if (!submit) e.preventDefault();
        tb_show("Megerősítés","#TB_inline?height=100&amp;width=200&amp;inlineId=myModalConfirm&amp;modal=true",null);
    })

    $('#yes').click(function(){
        $('form.confirm').trigger('submit', [true]);
    });


    $('#cancel').click(function(){
        tb_remove();
    });
```

Comment: did you tried `return true;` ?

Comment: yep, also a bunch of variations of return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submit` is a method not a property, you are missing `()`. You can use `trigger` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.confirm').submit(function(e, submit){
        if (!submit) e.preventDefault();
        tb_show("Megerősítés","#TB_inline?height=100&amp;width=200&amp;inlineId=myModalConfirm&amp;modal=true",null);
    })

    $('#yes').click(function(){
        $('form.confirm').trigger('submit', [true]);
    });


    $('#cancel').click(function(){
        b_remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to this post I already solved my problem :)
Can you explain the logic to this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is going to be to store whether the user clicked "Yes" in a variable, and if they did, let the form process as usual.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userClickedYes = false;

    $('form.confirm').submit(function(e){    
        if(!userClickedYes){
            e.preventDefault();
            tb_show("Megerősítés","#TB_inline?height=100&amp;width=200&amp;inlineId=myModalConfirm&amp;modal=true",null);
        }            
    });

    $('button#yes').click(function(){
        userClickedYes = true;
        $('form.confirm').submit();
    });
    $('button#cancel').click(function(){
        tb_remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Giant thanks to you, too but I don't want to declare variables out of the 'action fn' because the environment is so modular :S But this snippet already went to my treasure :)